# Can we download iTunes library songs from iOS application

Tags: ios, iphone, in-app-purchase, itunes

Is is possible to access the iTunes songs from iOS application. If its possible can we purchase particular song from iTunes library in my application using In-App Purchase.

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible. However you can access iPod music library with [iPod Library Access Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Audio/Conceptual/iPodLibraryAccess_Guide/Introduction/Introduction.html)

Comment: thank you for quick reply. As per your answer, we can not download or purchase songs from iTunes library in my iOS application. right?